# Heating pre cooked stew in kli sheini on Shabbat

Tags: halacha, shabbat, cooking-bishul

Is it permitted to heat (fully cooked) stew in a kli sheini on Shabbat?

This would obviously be edible, cold, and wet (covered with water and gravy) meat, vegetables, potatoes etc. so you would be taking an existing pot of boiling water, pouring it into a second pot, and then putting the stew to warm up in the second pot.

Is this (or something similar) brought down somewhere?

Comment: please clarify are you putting the stew gravy and all in the kli shani (btw will ruin the taste of your stew) or are you putting the pot of stew in the kli shani like a dubble boiler.

Comment: Putting the stew and all in the kli sheini @Efraym is what I mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cooking is forbidden on Shabbos but [re-heating is permitted](https://ph.yhb.org.il/en/01-10-03/) provided a certain number of conditions are met, e.g., the food is solid and already cooked (at least to a large extent), the device used to re-heat cannot be adjusted up and down and one doesn't give the appearance to cook.

**In your case, assuming the hot water was heated before Shabbat (as it can't be heated on Shabbat itself), it would be permitted to place pre-cooked food or a pot with pre-cooked stew in a large pot of hot water** ([since no one normally cooks this way, a.k.a. a bain-marie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bain-marie)).

Note this is valid is gravy is mixed into the rest of the food (e.g., if the food is moist). Reheating water of liquids on their own is always forbidden.

For sources, see e.g., [here](https://ph.yhb.org.il/en/01-10-02/) for general laws of cooking, [here](https://ph.yhb.org.il/en/01-10-03/) for re-heating, and the bottom of [here](https://ph.yhb.org.il/en/01-10-18/) for placing fully cooked food on a heat source that is not normally used for cooking.

I checked this with a Rosh Kollel in Bnei Brak but, of course, [consult your rabbi](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9146)
before implementing anything [you learn here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1734).